# Programmatically construct a condition for use in an if() statement

Tags: javascript

Let's assume for a moment that I have something like this:

```
if (document.getElementById('div1').innerHTML &&
    document.getElementById('div2').innerHTML &&
    document.getElementById('div3').innerHTML &&
    document.getElementById('div4').innerHTML &&
    document.getElementById('div5').innerHTML &&
    ...
    document.getElementById('div100').innerHTML)
```

Obviously typing out and maintaining a big conditional statement like this is problematic.

I would like some solution like:

```
var conditional = "";
for(var i = 1; i <= 100; i++){
  conditional += "document.getElementById('div" + i +"').innerHTML";
  if(i < 100) {
    conditional += " && ";
  }
}
if(interpretStringAsJSExpression(conditional)){
    console.log("all my divs have content");
}
```

Is something like this possible in JavaScript?

Great answers have been submitted, and I am sure that I and others will benefit from them. However, purely from a place of curiosity, is it possible to store and run JavaScript expressions or commands in strings?

Like I have proposed in my example: `interpretStringAsJSExpression(conditional)`

Comment: You can execute a string with `eval(conditional)`. It's almost always the wrong solution, though.

Comment: Maybe you are interested in [`Array.prototype.every`](https://developer.mozilla.org/it/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/every)

Comment: I approve of your curiosity.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

As the other answers said, you can solve your conditions problem more easily.

But, to answer your new question

> purely from a place of curiosity, is it possible to store and run
>   JavaScript expressions or commands in strings?

Yes, you can write JavaScript code to a string and execute it later with [eval](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/eval). Which you should not do if you are concerned with security or performance.

Comment: Since this most closely answers my question I am going to accept it, though I recognize that for the example I gave there are more direct solutions, and furthermore that `eval()` has its own problems.

Answer (score 26):

You can do the tests in a loop.

```
var allOK = true;
for (var i = 1; i <= 100; i++) {
    if (!document.getElementById("div"+i).innerHTML) {
        allOK = false;
        break;
    }
}
if (allOK) {
    console.log("all my divs have content");
}
```

You could also give all your DIVs a common class, then use a built-in iterator.

```
var allDivs = document.getElementsByClassName("divClass");
if (Array.from(allDivs).every(div => div.innerHTML)) {
    console.log("all my divs have content");
}
```

Comment: I suppose document.getElementById("div"+i).innerHTML will return a string not a boolean. isn't it?

Comment: @Gaurav An empty string is falsey.

Comment: +1, slow typing on my part and this is how I would do it. Didn't know about the built in iterator method.  very cool!

Comment: Pretty much any time you find yourself breaking out of a loop (especially if the loop just sets a variable), you should pull that out into a function instead.  The `break` becomes a `return`

Comment: You could use `[...allDivs]` instead of `Array.from`, although I don't think anything older than ES6 supports it.

Comment: @BlueRaja-DannyPflughoeft Creating a function to replace one isolated loop seems like overkill. Of course, `.every()` *is* that function in a general form.

Answer (score 8):

Why interpret a string of code? There are other means like `for` loops:

```
var conditionResult = true;
for(var i = 1; conditionResult && (i < 101); i++) {
    conditionResult = conditionResult && document.getElementById('div' + i).innerHTML;
}

if(conditionResult) {
    // Do something here
}
```

The `for` loop condition `conditionResult && (i < 101)` will break the loop once `conditionResult` is determined to be falsy; no need to keep looping in this case.

You can also use array methods like `some` and `every` if you have the elements in an array:

```
var arr = [/* array of DOM elements */];

var conditionResult = arr.every(elem => elem.innerHTML);   // This is equivalent to (innerHTML && innerHTML && ...)

var conditionResult = arr.some(elem => elem.innerHTML);    // This is equivalent to (innerHTML || innerHTML || ...)
```

Answer (score 2):

You can set `condition` to `true` and check each one, setting `condition` to false and break out of the loop if any are false.

```
var conditional = true;
for(var i = 1; i <= 100; i++){
  if (!document.getElementById('div' + i).innerHTML) {
        condition = false;
        break;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Use **document.querySelectorAll** for this type of operation

```js
// Get all the divs that have ids which start with div
var theDivs = document.querySelectorAll('[id^="div"]');
var i,l,el,divsWithContent = [];

// Loop through all theDivs
l = theDivs.length;
for(i = 0; i < l; i++) {
    // el is the div 
    el = theDivs[i];
    
    // Test to make sure the id is div followed by one or more digits
    if (/^div\d+$/.test(el.id)) {
        // If the div has something in it other than spaces, it's got content
        if (el.textContent.trim() !== "") {
            // Save the divs with content in the array
            divsWithContent.push(el.id);
        }
    }
}

// Show the results 
document.getElementById("result").textContent = divsWithContent.join("\n");
```

```html
<h1>Div test</h1>
<div id="div1">This</div>
<div id="div2">that</div>
<div id="div3"></div>
<div id="div4">and</div>
<div id="div5">the other thing</div>
<h2>Divs with content</h2>
<pre id="result"></pre>
```

Ref: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll

Answer (score 2):

Another option aside from `eval` is to use the [Function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function) constructor. `Function` is a bit more flexible and allows you to save compiled code instead of having to `eval` it each time.
They both carry similar security risks, however.

```js
var conditional = "";
for(var i = 1; i <= 6; i++){
  conditional += "document.getElementById('div" + i +"').innerHTML";
  if(i < 6) {
    conditional += " && ";
  }
}
const f = new Function('return (' + conditional + ') !== ""');

console.log(f());
```

```html
<div id="div1">1</div>
<div id="div2"></div>
<div id="div3">3</div>
<div id="div4">4</div>
<div id="div5"></div>
<div id="div6">6</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You could just store the `document.getElementById('divXX').innerHTML` items in an array, and then, just use

```
items.reduce((a, b) => a && b);
```

That way, you can change individual `div` elements in your expression without having to re-created the whole list

Comment: It's annoying that operators are not functions, otherwise this would be very nicely expressed as `items.reduce(&)`.

Comment: @JörgWMittag: it would. but I've seen few languages where you can write this

Comment: I think you need to use `&&` rather than `&`: `.innerHTML` is a string, but `&` performs bitwise AND on the bits of numbers, so the string is converted to a number. However, in this case, `.reduce((a, b) => a && b)` is the same as `.every(a => a)`, or even more simply, `['div1','div2', /*...*/ 'div100'].every(div => document.getElementById(div).innerHTML)`